# What caused CVE-2012-2459? How was it fixed?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development

Gavin Andresen made an announcement about this denial of service issue in 2012 [here](https://bitcointalk.org/?topic=81749), but it's light on technical details.

Comment: Just found the disclosure: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=102395.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full disclosure post is here: https://bitcointalk.org/?topic=102395

You can find it from the Bitcoin CVE list: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/CVEs